# Handling dynamic-sized structs from byte sequence

Tags: c#, networking, struct, unsafe

I'm dealing with packet parsing from network stream. The sending side is already implemented, and i'm only implementing client-side, so data should be parsed as-is. Previously all packets were const-sized, so I did it this way:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public unsafe ref struct MyConstSizedStruct
{
    //example structure
    public uint Data1;
    public byte Data2;
    public fixed byte Version[6];
}
```

So the size of this is 4 + 1 + 6 = 11. Now I receive data to buffer and point it to a structure.

```
public unsafe void HandleMyConstSizedStruct(ushort length, byte[] data)
{
    MyConstSizedStruct pkt;
    fixed (byte* ptr = &data[0])
        pkt = *(MyConstSizedStruct*)ptr;
    //dealing with data
}
```

At this point everything was ok, but now I got something more complicated:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public unsafe struct MyDynamicSizedStruct
{
    public uint Data1;
    public uint Data2;
    //here we have null-terminated utf-8 string of unknown length
    public char* User;
    public uint Data3;
    public uint Data4;
    public byte Data5;
    public byte[] RestOfData;
}
```

So the problem is: now the packet is dynamically-sized, the size is received as a prefix ushort from network, but simple casting doesn't work because:

1. Null-terminated string
2. byte[] is considered a managed type, so now struct is considered as managed also, so I can't cast it

So is there a nice way to interpret such structure, or I should deal with BinaryReader for this particular case?

**Edit:** some ideas:

1. The offset of `char*` is always 8, so we can calculate the length of char buffer as indexof zero-byte, starting at 8.
2. Somehow replace `char*` with `Span<char>` to set a length of this buffer in a struct? Or shift Data3 by calculated offset possible with some pointer assigning?
3. After setting the correct padding of char buffer, reading byte[] array shouldn't be a problem, since we know the total size, we can do `totalsize - 17 /*size of all DataX*/ - /*char size*/` to get byte[] size

Comment: `Marshal.PtrToStructure` maybe?

Comment: Won't it produce the same as just casting but with data copy? Since the end of ```char* User``` is uknown, when I cast bytes to struct, everything past Data2 is considered as User bytes

Comment: You need the right data types and attributes `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr)] public string User;` and `RestOfData` you will need to marshal separately using `Marshal.Copy`

Comment: @Charlieface I tried your suggestion, ByValTStr requires ```[MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = X)] public string user;```which is actually the same as ```public fixed byte User[X]```, but the size is unknown at compile time and can be at [2..16] amount of chars (which is I don't know how many in bytes would be). I also tried ```[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str)]``` and some other types, but those throw ```AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found some solution (probably not the best, but still looks better for me than BinaryReader.
Assuming we have this struct

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    unsafe struct MyStruct
    {
        public uint Data1;
        public uint Data2;

        public char* user;

        public uint Data3;
        public uint Data4;
        public byte* restOfData;
    }
```

We have a constant offset of 8 (4 + 4) till `char*` and 8 from end of `char*` to `byte*`. So what we can do is use `MemoryMarshal` class.

```
const int offset = 8;
MyStruct pkt;
fixed (byte* ptr = &buffer[0])
{
    pkt = *(MyStruct*)ptr;
} //here we get all prefix fields as normal.

//Get index of start of field after char*
int index = Array.IndexOf<byte>(buffer, 0, offset) + 1;
var memory = MemoryMarshal.CreateFromPinnedArray(buffer, offset, size - offset);
index -= offset;

//Parse all fields
string user = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memory.Span[0..index]);
pkt.Data3 = BitConverter.ToUInt32(memory.Span[index..]);
pkt.Data4 = BitConverter.ToUInt32(memory.Span[(index+4)..]);

//Set rest of data
fixed (byte* ptr = memory.Span[(index + 8)..])
    pkt.restOfData = ptr;
```